# Denwer и переход по внешним ссылкам

Tags: denwer

Интересует следующий вопрос:
Установлен локальный сервер denwer. На страничке запускаемой в его директории добавлена ссылка на внешний сайт, но при клике на нее денвер выдает следующее:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /url(http://google.ru/) on this server.

Пример ссылки:

```
<a href="url(https://www.google.ru/)" target="blank">ссылка</a>
```

Можно ли настроить денвер, чтобы он разрешал делать переходы?

Comment: Денвер тут не при чем. У вас ссылка кривая.

Comment: `<a id="ab" href="url(https://www.google.ru/)" target="blank"><span class="baner-title"><span class="title">ссылка</span><span class="fon"></span></span><img alt="image" src="/img/image.png"></a>`
Что здесь кривого?

Comment: `url(https://www.google.ru/)` вот это, вместо `https://www.google.ru/`, вот что кривого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переношу из комментария:

У вас используется в качестве ссылки `url(https://www.google.ru/)`, а надо было указывать ссылку напрямую: `https://www.google.ru/`.

Сейчас `url(https://www.google.ru/)` расценивается как относительная ссылка и он вряд ли существует на сервере, из-за чего вы и видите сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: По-хорошему, `url(https://www.google.ru/)` - это относительная ссылка, а не абсолютная.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, вы правы, я перепутал понятия